# How to click on link inside table selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium

I m trying to click on the link that inside a table row that is under the second "doctype" but when I use the xpath/title it doesn't see it it only see the top  not the child one.

```
WebElement divList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/iframe/html/body/div[2]"));
divList.getSize();
System.out.println(">>>>??" + divList.getSize());

List<WebElement> allCreditCards = creditCardsList.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + x + "']/li"));
System.out.println("CardsAre: >" + allCreditCards.size());
 for (int i = 0; i <= allCreditCards.size(); i++) {
     int temp = i + 1;
     String creditcard = allCreditCards.get(i).getText();
     System.out.println(" i is = " + creditcard + " " + i);
     if (creditcard.equals()) {
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + x + "']/li[" + temp + "]/a")).click();
         break;
```

Please see attached image for the html page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the switchTo `iframe` part. Unless you provide the code you have tried with, it's hard to know what has gone wrong exactly.

```
//there is an `iframe` and you need to switchTo that `iframe`
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("EventSearchFrame")));

//the following css should find the a tag based on the partial title match
By byCss = By.cssSelector("th>a[title^='Attendee Type event']");
//wait for the element to load properly using explicit wait
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss));

myDynamicElement.click();
```

When you are done working inside the `iframe` you need to switch focus back to `defaultContent()` in order to the `Selenium` know you are outside of `iframe`

Use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
//continue
```

Comment: the driver.switchTo() is a nice feature for changing document focus

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Firstly check which version of selenium your are using, and which browser you have selected for your driver. This is an old link, but highlights that sometimes the issue is outside of your control and it's best that you upgrade: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6111

Secondly selectors are usually used to search within the document. As you are looking inside an iframe by default this is a different document. Ensure that your xpath is able to first locate the iframe and then the document within. Paste your xpath if you want some more help with this.

Comment: Thanks
I m new to selenium just learning so is going to be hard to locate and put the focus on the frame for me.

Comment: if you need to just 'click' something then programs like AutoIT are great for writing little executable scripts to do things that are outside of what's obvious in your testing tools

Comment: @ABrowne `WebDriver` just handles the `xpath` with `iframe` fine if the coding done properly. I do not think there is a need to implement `AutoIT` just to handle this scenario

Comment: @Saifur - completely agree with you, using the driver.switchTo() will solve this. The mention of AutoIT is just good to know if all other routes look impossible.

Comment: such as if you are trying to perform formating options in tinyMCE, it is faster just to write a script to do it than to pull out all of the xpath handles to isolate the correct buttons. Another example is file saving and uploading through the default browser driver which is complex to get right.